# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined avatar of bot problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I made a command to change my bot avatar, I made it like this:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "profile")) {
    var image = message.attachments.first().url;
    client.user.setAvatar(image);
  }
});
```

However, I get this error when I use the command with a link to change the picture. So, if I want to change the picture, I must use attached pictures only, not a link to a picture.

Comment: What does `message.attachments.first()` return?

Comment: it's the the attachment of the text

Comment: The error says it is `undefined`

Comment: so how can identify it ?? is there is a var or const to put?

Comment: I would use the browser's devtools to find out what `message` is, then `message.attachments`, etc.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Why is this tagged as both Python and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Looks like .first() function doesn't exists

```
var image = message.attachments[0].url;
```

Comment: the same problem

Comment: can you see what is the output of ```message.attachments``` ?

Comment: when i changed the first() the bot didn't even use the attachment picture it it gives me the same error but when i made it back it first() it returned to use the attachment picture but the problem is with the url

Comment: iam new to the java script so there might be somethings i don't understand

Comment: @HazemKamel *javascript (one word )

Answer (score 0):

you can`t use `message.attachments` as file to update you bot avatar.
You need to save it first, and then upload with patch to local storage.

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "profile")) {
        if (message.attachments.size === 0) return message.reply('you need add image to change bots avatar')
        let file = fs.createWriteStream(`./${message.attachments.array()[0].name}`);
        let request = http.get(message.attachments.array()[0].url, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function() {
                client.user.setAvatar(`./${message.attachments.array()[0].name}`)
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: When i used this i must put a picture as an attachment i want to put just the link and the bot change the picture to the picture in the link u got it? and special thanks for the code

Comment: put picture, but possible to add some condition to allow url.